# URL redirection wont work always?

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, if-statement

Im Workin on a Webapplication in PHP with CodeIgniter, and im stuck :P
Its very difficult to explain, so i show it with an example.

I have normal CodeIgniter Controller. In this Controller i have a function like this:

```
<?php
public function groups($subdomain ='') {

    $this->load->library('MyLogin');
    $user_id = $this->mylogin->logged_in();


    if ($subdomain == '') {
        .....
    } elseif ($subdomain == 'create') {
        .....
    } elseif ($subdomain == 'join') {
        .....
    } elseif ($subdomain == 'leave') {
        .....
    } elseif ($subdomain == 'assign') {
        .....
    } else {
        .....
    }
}
```

The logged_in Function checks if the user who's loading this page (sub pages) is logged in. If not he gets automatically redirected in the logged_in function like this:

```
echo header("Location: /user/login");
```

5 Minutes ago this worked well. Now i created a new subdomain 'assign'.

Now if im not logged in and try to Connect to one of the following URLS i always get redirected

```
    localhost/user/groups
    localhost/user/groups/2
    localhost/user/groups/create
    localhost/user/groups/join
    localhost/user/groups/leave
```

But if im connecting to

```
    localhost/user/groups/assign
```

he tries to load this page (what does not work because the $user_id is empty).
Why the ... does this happen?

Regards Teifun2

Comment: `header()` has **NO** return value. `echo header(...)` is utterly pointless.

Comment: Just for the record, your usage of `$subdomain` is not for that of a subdomain, but a subdirectory.

Comment: @MarcB Ups :P thanks will change this, (but is not solving my problem)

Comment: @DanLugg yes :P im from switzerland so i dont always get the right words sorry XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you modify the logged_in() function from this:

```
echo header("Location: /user/login");
```

To this:

```
header("Location: /user/login");
exit;
```

I think that will solve the problem. The echo has nothing to do with it, it's just superfluous.

Comment: You are my Hero :D Can you explain why this works? I mean why it works for 3 other subdirectorys and not for the assign ?

Comment: The header() function simply causes PHP to send a header value to the browser, assigning some value. In some cases, this is the 'Location' value which suggests that the browser should redirect to some other location. At the code level, the header() function is not like a return statement, and so code after it will continue to execute. Since you generally always expect a location header to be the end point of a page load, it's always a good idea to exit after any location header.

Answer (score 0):

use $_session while logging user in...! so he will reamain logged in even after refresh and page change..! And empty values wont pass.

Comment: the problem is not to stay logged in, its more that one of 4 elseif statements dont get that hes actually allredy redirected.